# Create jquery plugin : run only once per selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, instance

I'm trying to create a plugin suited for my needs which adds some functions to tables. There are of course thousands of plugins like dataTables.js etc. but a lightweight solution is more suitable for what I'm trying to do.

Problem(s): If there are 2 tables or more, the code runs multiple times on each table and of course if you filter one table, paginate one table and change the page of each... it applies to all.

Any help would be appreciated and if you have improvement ideas they're welcome ! Once I'm done I will publish this on github if anyone is interested in a simple version of datatables... !

https://jsfiddle.net/ygery/gm02mvpk/

```
function tableOptions(selector, paginate, npages, filter, responsive) {

  var $table = $(selector);
  var currentPage = 0;

  function tablePaginate() {
    $table.bind('paginate', {
      pages: npages
    }, function(event) {
      $('.pagination').remove();
      // if(npages != )
      //alert(event.data.pages);
      var $row = $table.find('tbody tr:not(.hidden)').addClass('row-pagination');
      $row.hide()
      $row.slice(currentPage * npages, (currentPage + 1) * npages).show();
      var numRows = $table.find('.row-pagination').length;

      var numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / npages);
      var $pager = $('<ul class="pagination"></ul>');

      $('<li class="table-prev"></li>').html('<a href="#"><</a>').bind('click', {
        prevPage: currentPage - 1
      }, function(event) {
        if (currentPage != 0) {
          currentPage = event.data['prevPage'];
          $table.trigger('paginate');
          $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
          $(this).hide();
        }

      }).appendTo($pager).addClass('clickable');

      for (var page = 0; page < numPages; page++) {
        $('<li class="table-page" data-page=' + parseInt(page + 1) + '></li>').html('<a href="#">' + parseInt(page + 1) + '</a>').bind('click', {
          newPage: page
        }, function(event) {

          currentPage = event.data['newPage'];
          //$table.trigger('paginate');
          $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        }).appendTo($pager).addClass('clickable');
      }

      $('<li class="table-next"></li>').html('<a href="#">></a>').bind('click', {
        nextPage: currentPage + 1
      }, function(event) {
        if (currentPage != numPages - 1) {
          currentPage = event.data['nextPage'];
          //$table.trigger('paginate');
          $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        }

      }).appendTo($pager).addClass('clickable');


      $pager.insertAfter($table);
      if (currentPage == 0) {
        $('.table-prev').addClass('disabled').attr('onclick', 'event.preventDefault();');
      }
      if (currentPage == numPages - 1) {
        $('.table-next').addClass('disabled').attr('onclick', 'event.preventDefault();');
      }
      $('li[data-page="' + parseInt(currentPage + 1) + '"]').addClass('active');

      if (numPages > 5) {
        var $this = parseInt(currentPage + 1);
        $('.table-page').hide();
        if (currentPage == 0) {
          currentPage = currentPage + 1;
        }
        for (var page = currentPage; page < currentPage + 2; page++) {
          $('.table-page[data-page="' + parseInt(page + 1) + '"]').show();
          if (page == currentPage + 1) {
            var dots = '<li class="disabled" onclick="event.preventDefault();"><a href="#">...</a></li>';
            $('.table-page[data-page="' + parseInt(page + 1) + '"]').after(dots);
          }
        }
        for (var page = currentPage; page > currentPage - 1; page--) {
          $('.table-page[data-page="' + parseInt(page) + '"]').show();
          //if(page == currentPage+1) {
          //  var dots = '<li class="disabled" onclick="event.preventDefault();"><a href="#">...</a></li>';
          //  $('.table-page[data-page="'+parseInt(page - 1)+'"]').after(dots);
          //}
        }
      }

    });
    $table.trigger('paginate');
  }

  function tableFilter() {
    $(".table-search").keyup(function() {
      $('li[data-page="1"]').click();
      var input = $(this);
      var $row = $table.find('tbody tr');
      var $cell = $row.find('td');

      if (input.val() != '') {
        $row.addClass('hidden').removeClass('row-pagination');
        $($cell).each(function(i, obj) {
          if ($(obj).find('input').length) {
            var $content = $(obj).find('input').val().toLowerCase().indexOf(input.val().toLowerCase());
          } else {
            if ($(obj).find('select').length) {
              var $content = $(obj).find('select option:selected').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(input.val().toLowerCase());
            } else {
              if ($(obj).text().length) {
                var $content = $(obj).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(input.val().toLowerCase());
              } else {
                var $content = $(obj).html().toLowerCase().indexOf(input.val().toLowerCase());
              }
            }

          }
          if ($content > -1 && input.val()) {
            $(obj).parent().removeClass('hidden');
            $(obj).parent().addClass('row-pagination');
          }
        });
        $table.trigger('paginate');

      } else {
        $table.find('tr').removeClass('hidden').addClass('row-pagination');
        $table.trigger('paginate');
      }

    });
  }

  function tableResponsive() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
      if ($(window).width() < 767) {
        if (!$('.responsive-toggle').length) {
          $table.find('thead tr th:first-child').before('<td class="responsive-toggle"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></i></td>');
          $table.find('tbody tr td:first-child').before('<td class="responsive-toggle"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></i></td>');

        }
        var max = $table.width();
        //alert(max);
      } else {
        $('.responsive-toggle').remove();
      }
    }).resize();


  }

  $table.each(function() {
    if (paginate || filter) {
      var $header = '<div class="col-sm-2 table-pagination-select"></div><div class="col-sm-6 table-options"></div><div class="col-sm-4 table-search-input"></div><hr />';
      $table.before($header);
      $table.wrap('<div class="col-md-12"></div>');
    }
    if (paginate) {
      var $target = $('.table-pagination-select');
      var $select = '<select name="" id="" class="form-control table-select"><option value="10">10</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="100">100</option><option value="all">Tous</option></select>';
      $($select).appendTo($target);
      //$('.table-select').select2();
      tablePaginate();
    }
    if (filter) {
      var $target = $('.table-search-input');
      var $searcher = '<input type="text" class="form-control table-search" placeholder="Rechercher..." />';
      $($searcher).appendTo($target);
      tableFilter();
    }
    if (responsive) {
      tableResponsive();
    }



  })

}

tableOptions('.table', true, 10, true, true);
```

Comment: If you want to create jquery plugin you should use `$.fn.tableOptions = function() { ... }` so you can call it using: `$('.table').tableOptions()`

Comment: Just curious about your plugin functionality. would you like to describe it a little more? we can chat on https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100303/jquery-plugin-discussion-on-a-question

Comment: @jcubic - is there any documentation on how to create these functions ? I saw this syntax a lot but I'm still learning !

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: If you use `$('.table-prev')` you need to use `$pager.find('.table-prev')` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can set data on jQuery object:

```
function tableOptions(selector, paginate, npages, filter, responsive) {

  var $table = $(selector);
  if ($table.data('table')) {
     return;
  } else {
     $table.data('table', true);
  }
```

Comment: I probably missed something but that's not working... would you mind to show me how to use that in the jsfiddle ?! I built the function with $.fn thank you very much it makes a lot more sense !